# Union of multiple sets in a list

Tags: python, set, set-comprehension

This is my code.

```
s = set()
for x in [ {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,1} ]:
    s |= x
```

It returns `set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`.

Is it possible to use set comprehension in such a case? How can I write it shorter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### `set.union`

```
set.union(*[{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,1}])
# {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Why do you need a loop at all? Use `set.union`, it lets you compute the union of more than two sets (containers) at a time.  I say "containers", because the second (and onwards) arguments need not be sets at all.

```
set.union(*[{1,2}, [3,4], [5,1]])
# {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

The first, however, needs to be. Alternatively,

```
set().union(*[[1,2], [3,4], [5,1]])
# {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

When calling `union` on a set object (and not the class), none of the arguments need be sets.

---

### `functools.reduce`

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(set.union, [{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,1}])
# {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

This performs a pairwise reduction, accumulating a result. Not nearly as good as the first option, however.

Comment: Instead of `{1, 2}.union(*[[3,4], [5,1]])` you can also use `set().union(*[{1,2}, [3,4], [5,1]])`.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want a set comprehension here:

```
lst = [{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,1}]
{elem for set_ in lst for elem in set_}
```